# Ruby On Rails Rolify + CanCanCan + Devise allow user to edit only their posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan, rolify

I have built `Ruby On Rails` application using [Devise + CanCanCan + rolify Tutorial](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial).

Here is my `Ability` model:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

I want to allow user edit their own posts, and read posts by others.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to pass the `user_id` to the [`hash conditions`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities#hash-of-conditions):

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id #-> CRUD own posts only
      can :read, :all #-> read everything
    end
  end
end
```

This would allow you to use:

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<%= render @posts %>

#app/views/posts/_post.html.erb
<% if can? :read, post %>
   <%= post.body %>
   <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), if can? :edit, post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks man, I spent like 6 hours the other day on something similar.

Comment: Well, I'm quite new to ruby and ruby on rails in a general, I don't know what would I do without a SO (Obviously,  I'd read a docs, but it'd take too much time) :)

Comment: Honestly, the docs are best for *reference*; if you want to achieve something specific, seeing what others have done is far more efficient

Comment: It doesn't work in my case (Rails 6.0.3.2), part of link "if can? :edit, post" causes view to crash. But on another side, I don't know how to fix it so that it would work. Putting <% if can? :edit, Post %> before link makes "Edit" to appear when it shouldn't appear, and clicking on it gives "You are not authorized to access this page."

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Richard Peck's answer. However, I would just like to point out that catering for a guest user (not logged in) is not needed. An initializer is invoked on instantiation of a new object (i.e an object's constructor).

Thus, the above Ability class could be as follows:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

 def initialize(user)

  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :manage, Post, user_id: user.id #-> CRUD own posts only
    can :read, :all #-> read everything
  end
 end
end
```